# JavaScript/jQuery submit function/AJAX call works from console, not from linked file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried looking through at least a dozen questions asking about AJAX/jQuery failures, but none seem to be my issue.

I have a site that relies on AJAX calls to load different pieces as the user logs in and interacts. Back end is all in PHP. I HAD everything working as far as I know, but somehow over the course of sitting online for a few weeks, a few random things have stopped working. Hacked? Just bugs? I don't know. This function was fully tested and functional when I deployed it.

I'm testing it in Firefox and Chrome for the time being.

First off: I have a few forms which, depending on the user's choice, load other forms on submit. At the end of the last form there is also a submit button. All of them are using POST (is this my problem? too many submit functions/AJAX calls running concurrently?).

If I'm on the page, open the console, and copy/paste the code to run it that way, it performs exactly as it should.

When I have the code in it's OWN file, wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {` it fails, without any warnings or errors in the log.

If I have it in the .JS file with the rest of the JS, it also fails with no information.

```
        $('#take_att').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'tools/attendance.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#take_att').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#controls').empty();
                    $('#controls').append(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

It's not preventing default (so it IS letting the form submit) and therefore refreshing the page (because action='').

I can't really make a JS fiddle of it without combining a number of different files' HTML and simulating form inputs, and unfortunately can't give login access.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: whether the element `$('#take_att')` is created dynamically? are you sure the script is executed from the js file

Comment: Can you add some console logging statement in the dom ready handler like `console.log('form', $('#take_att').length)`

Comment: $('#take_att') is a form loaded via AJAX, the form itself is hard coded in the PHP file (which also processes the data), but all of the possible inputs (radio buttons with labels, and hidden fields) are created dynamically.

Comment: Also, there is a submit function which makes an AJAX call to load this form, and that works fine.

All the other submit functions/AJAX calls in the JS file seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the reason, since you said the form is loaded via ajax you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Since the form is loaded via ajax when your dom ready handler is fired the form may not have already loaded to the dom so the selector `$('#take_att')` may not return any element thus the submit handler will not get attached to the form.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on('submit', '#take_att', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'tools/attendance.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#take_att').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#controls').empty();
                $('#controls').append(data);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: So, because this form is not part of the DOM when the document is loaded initially, it can't be targeted directly like this? I need to target the div containing it?

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense. I never thought about it that way. Your solution works perfect :)